# How to tie tooltips to the currently hovered SERIES, not just the point?

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart, with these bits of code:

```
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var tmp = '<b>'+this.series.name+'</b>';
                return tmp;
            }
        }
```

and

```
                states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 8
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And by and large, it works perfectly.

But if two lines share a point (they both pass through x = 0, y = 4, for example), and the mousecursor is closer to that point than the next ones along the lines, then the tooltip always returns the first series name, rather than that of whichever line is currently highlighted by hovering over it.

Is there a simple fix?

Comment: You could try and use `tooltip.shared: true`. This would apply to all tooltip points, though.

Comment: I added that and it made all series points for a specific value of x become highlighted, while the tooltip itself no longer worked at all?

Comment: Well, you would need to modify your formatter as well if you do shared. Take a look at the docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter

Comment: You can also replace line type series with the scatter and declare lineWidth:2 param.

Comment: With the shared tooltip, how does one discern which series line is currently in the "hover" state, @wergeld, or is that not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line type series with the scatter and declare `lineWidth:2` param. Then set [stickyTracking](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.stickyTracking) as false.